# Can the assumption that the $E[u_i|X_i]=0$ in this regression scenario?

Tags: regression

The question is:

> Given the following linear regression between $X$ and $Y$:
>
> $Y_i=\alpha+\beta X_i+u_i$ , and that
>
> $Cov(X_i,E_i)<0, \; Cov(X_i,F_i)>0$, and $u_i=E_i+F_i$
>
> Is it possible that the assumption $E[u_i|X_i]=0$ hold?

I suppose the only time when it does hold when $G(X_i)+H(X_i)=0$, where  $G(X_i)=E_i$ and $H(X_i)=F_i$?

Comment: I will give you a hint. Look up the formula for the conditional expectation of a sum on Wikipedia (or derive it) and apply it to your sum. If that has to be zero, that will imply something about that formula.